# Angular2/Ionic2: Save Image from gallery and send as attachment via mailto

Tags: sqlite, angular, ionic2, mailto, ngcordova

I am trying to save an image in my sqlite db and send it via the mailto service. Here is my code:

```
takepic() {
    var options = {
        quality: 80,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        allowEdit: false,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    Camera.getPicture(options).then((data) => {
        var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        image.src = imageURI;
        this.zone.run(() => this.image = image.src);
        this.storage.query("UPDATE verifyBL SET Thu = '" + this.image + "' WHERE id = 2").then((data) => {
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error.err));
        });
    }, (error) => {
        alert(error);
    });
}
```

And when sending it via mailto it looks like:

```
(click)="mailIT('mailto:'+post.email +'?body=' +emailText + '&attachment='+imageSC)"
```

The body text will be send correctly but no attachment. I tried it with the base64 version, but no success either. The function on the page1.js looks like:

```
mailIT(passedMail) {
    window.location = passedMail;
}
```

And imsageSC is defined like:

```
onPageWillEnter() {
        this.storage.query("SELECT * FROM verifyBL").then((data) => {
            if(data.res.rows.length > 0) {
            this.emailText = data.res.rows.item(1).Sch;
            this.imageSC = data.res.rows.item(1).Thu;
        }
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error.err));
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the `mailIT()` method referred to by the click event?

Comment: I edited the question. But the mailIT() function is a simple window.location

Comment: Thanks! Where is `imageSC` defined and where is `takepic()` being called?

Comment: takepic() is called on different page called sedcard-page.js. As you can see the image is saved then in the sqlite table verifyBL. I edited the part where imageSC is defined

Comment: @jhhoff02 I am using base64 img again its working fine when just showing the uploaded pics. No matter where. Isn`t it possible to save this image inside the apps storage as an image? Then use the path to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the the spec ([RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068)), attachments cannot be attached to emails using the `mailto:` scheme. That's why your `attachment=...` is being ignored. If you want to add an attachment, you'll have to use another method. Here are two options. I haven't actually tested them, but I believe either would work:

### Using Cordova Email Plugin and [Ionic Native](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/src/plugins/emailcomposer.ts)

(NOTE: [this may not be stable](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/src/plugins/emailcomposer.ts#L9).) First install the Cordova email plugin and also the `ionic-native` plugin from the console:

```bash
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-email-composer
$ npm install --save ionic-native
```

Then in your component:

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController, Storage, SqlStorage} from "ionic-angular";
import {EmailComposer} from "ionic-native";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "build/pages/mypage/mypage.html"
})
export class MyPage {

    storage: Storage;
    emailText: string;
    imageSC: string;

    constructor(public nav: NavController) {
        this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
        this.storage.query("SELECT * FROM verifyBL").then((data) => {
            if(data.res.rows.length > 0) {
                this.emailText = data.res.rows.item(1).Sch;
                this.imageSC = data.res.rows.item(1).Thu;
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error.err));
        });
    }

    mailIt() {
        EmailComposer.isAvailable().then((avail: boolean) => {
            if (available) {
                let email = {
                    to: this.post.email, // not sure where you set this...
                    attachments: [
                        this.imageSC
                    ],
                    body: this.emailText,
                    subject: "Email with attachment",
                    isHtml: true
                };
                EmailComposer.open(email);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Using Mailgun

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController, Storage, SqlStorage} from "ionic-angular";
import {Http, Request, RequestMethod, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "build/pages/mypage/mypage.html"
})
export class MyPage {

    storage: Storage;
    emailText: string;
    imageSC: string;
    mailgunUrl: string;
    mailgunApiKey: string;

    constructor(public nav: NavController, private http: Http) {
        this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
        this.storage.query("SELECT * FROM verifyBL").then((data) => {
            if(data.res.rows.length > 0) {
                this.emailText = data.res.rows.item(1).Sch;
                this.imageSC = data.res.rows.item(1).Thu;
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error.err));
        });
        this.mailgunUrl = "YOUR_MAILGUN_URL";
        this.mailgunApiKey = window.btoa("api:key-MAILGUN_API_KEY_HERE");
    }

    mailIt() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + this.mailgunApiKey);
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        this.http.request(new Request({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + this.mailgunUrl + "/messages",
            body: "from=test@example.com&to=" + this.post.email + "&subject=Email+with+attachment&text=" + this.emailText,
            attachment: this.imageSC, // not sure about this, maybe [this.imageSC]
            headers: requestHeaders
        }))
        .subscribe(
            success => { console.log("Success", success);},
            error   => { console.log("Error",   error); }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hej thx for your help I am really bussy working right now with a big company for their homepage. Since the bounty expires in two days and I don`t know if I have the time. I mark this awnser as correct. I really apreciate your help and would be grateful for more help if needed. TY very much